# LVM - 2 PVs in a disk without partitioning

Tags: lvm

It is possible to create another PV if the backing disk has free space which is not used by first PV?

```
[root@bender green]# lsblk 
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  64G  0 disk 
|-sda1                8:1    0   1G  0 part /boot
`-sda2                8:2    0  63G  0 part 
  |-rootvg-rootlv   253:0    0  55G  0 lvm  /
  `-rootvg-swaplv   253:1    0   8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                   8:16   0  16G  0 disk 
`-vg_green-lv_green 253:2    0  10G  0 lvm  /mnt/green
sdc                   8:32   0  16G  0 disk 
`-vg_red-lv_red     253:3    0  16G  0 lvm  /mnt/red
```

The idea is that I want to use the available disk space in the second VG(vg_red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it's impossible - in lieu of partitions, you could set up custom loop devices (`losetup --offset --sizelimit`) or `dmsetup` linear mappings. Or you could do crazy things like add it to VG green, create green-LV to use as PV for VG red. Which would technically make the space useable for the VG red but with a dependency on VG green.

However, you don't really want to do it that way.

Just set up a partition table. Even if it means adding a new disk and migrating data over with `pvmove`, or backup and copy data. It's the proper way to do it - each disk should be partitioned first, then partitions should be used for everything else. Never put stuff on the raw disk directly, or you'll be stuck in your situation where you can't really add partitions.

If that's not an option, I'd rather `vgmerge` green and red into one and you can still decide what to allocate where on `lvcreate` so things will effectively be stored the same way.